# strange behavior of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I make a `UIScrollView` which's width is changing with touch.  When the current view controller segues to the next one, I want to save the UIScrollView's width. When the view controller is shown again, the `UIScrollView`'s width should be restored.

```
//TouZiViewController is the current view controller
@implementation TouZiViewController
...
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toTouZi2"])
    {   //TouZi2ViewController is the destination view controller
        TouZi2ViewController *viewController2=[segue destinationViewController];

        //huatiaoRect is CGRect,fullHuaTiao is the outlet of UIScrollView
        viewController2.huatiaoRect=self.fullHuaTiao.frame;

    }
}
@end


@implementation TouZi2ViewController
...
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toTouZi"])
    {
        TouZiViewController *viewController=[segue destinationViewController];
        [viewController loadView];

        viewController.fullHuaTiao.frame=self.huatiaoRect;

    }

}
@end
```

The problem is that when I come back from the second view controller, the `UIScrollView`'s position is much higher than before. Why is this?
**UPDATE**
Now I find that the problem is because of autoresizing.I change autoresizing in storyboard,then it works well.

Comment: Why don't you log the values of `huatiaoRect` in each of these places and see if `origin.y` is changing somewhere?  `NSLog(NSStringFromRect(self.huatiaoRect));`

Comment: @SeamusCampbell I log in viewDidLoad,the origin.y is not changed,but actually it's changed.I think the change is out of viewDidLoad.

Comment: I think you need to find everywhere you change or update the value of `huatiaoRect` and log it.  Perhaps you are editing the origin in places you only intend to be editing the width.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be calling loadview method before setting the frame.If not log the Frame values and find where value is changed

change to this and give it a try

```
    viewController.fullHuaTiao.frame=self.huatiaoRect;
    [viewController loadView];
```